# Is there a way to stop the activity from closing itself once it is called?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to display a google map showing the current location. however when the map activity is called, it opens the activity, displays the map then the app closes. How do I prevent this from happening?
Below is the java code for the map activity.

```java
package com.example.nibebe;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.geofire.GeoFire;
import com.firebase.geofire.GeoLocation;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;


public class DriverMapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment;
    FusedLocationProviderClient fusedLocationClient;
    Button mLogout;
    Button mDriver, mPassenger;

    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_driver_map);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.driver_map);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMapActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }else{
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
        }

        fusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        mLogout = findViewById(R.id.logout);
        mDriver = findViewById(R.id.driver);
        mPassenger = findViewById(R.id.passenger);
        mLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DriverMapActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mPassenger.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(DriverMapActivity.this,PassengerMapActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        });

        mDriver.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You are already a driver!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        /* Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));*/
        fusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                        // Got last known location. In some rare situations this can be null.
                        if (location != null) {
                            //pass the two parameter
                            LatLng sydney = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                            mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney)
                                    .title("Marker in My current location"));
                            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
                        }
                    }
                });
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMapActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        buildGoogleApiClient();
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient()
    {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(DriverMapActivity.this, new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if(getApplicationContext()!=null){
            mLastLocation = location;

            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude());

            mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(11));

            String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
            DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");

            GeoFire geofire = new GeoFire(ref);
            geofire.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        }
    }

    final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DriversAvailable");

        GeoFire geofire = new GeoFire(ref);
        geofire.removeLocation(userId);
    }
}
```

I expect the map to be loaded and show the current location without the app crashing.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: by closes, do you mean, crashes? if so, please provide your stacktrace in the question.

Comment: You should show logcat.